# Building a promise that releases a warning

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

Im trying to release a warning every time the server/the function needs more than 3 seconds do answer or finish.

For example:

```
  addAval(avalid) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.uri}/path/add`, avalid);
  }
```

or

```
getPath(){
...
}
```

If any of this functions only posts/finishes after 4 seconds, the app releases an warning/console log with that information.

How can I do it?

Tried this:

```
let promiseA = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let wait = setTimeout(() => {
    clearTimout(wait);
    resolve(createWarning());
  }, 200)
})

let race = Promise.race([
  promiseA])
```

Comment: start two async task and let them race, remember to cancel the warning.

Comment: but you should read [ask] and provide what have you tried.

Comment: done, updated the code

Comment: sorry for forgot the [mcve] link (although it's in [ask]), and please explain your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement that method:

```
const sendRequstWithTimeout = (requestMethod, timeout) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      console.warn('timeout request');
      reject('timeout'); // Remove this line if you don't reject promise by timeout.
    }, timeout);

    const result = requestMethod().then((result) => {
      resolve(result);
    }).catch((error) => {
      reject(error)
    }).finally(() => {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    });

  })
};
```

And use it:

```
sendRequstWithTimeout(() => fetch('https://example.com'), 1) // In your case, 3000 instead of 1.
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
   })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error); // Here yout can catch error from back-end or error as a result timeout.
  })
```

Comment: this is not correct, at least the warning would always be logged afaict.

Comment: @appleapple Yes, you are right. I fixed my answer. Thank you!